# Javascript UTF encoding

Tags: javascript, html, forms, character-encoding

I m trying to make a simple order form and i have 2 problems. The first one is the encoding 
of **the email that is sent** when my form fields contain non-utf chars. 
the second problem is the layout of the email that is sent. I tried using

```
document.writeln ("<OPTION>"+prodlist[i].name)
```

but it does not change line and the output produced is all messed up.

I appreciate any help. Here is my code :

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="application/javascript; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Order Form</TITLE>
<SCRIPT charset="UTF-8">

//Global Variables

var RowsInForm = 10 //How many rows will be in the order details form

var ProductsInList = 4 //Must equal highest subscript in product list



// Function to create a new empty array that starts at 1.

function MakeArray(n) {

this.length = n

for (var i = 1; i<= n; i++) {

this[i] = 0

}

return this

}

// Function to create a new, empty array that starts at zero.

function BuildZeroArray(n) {

this.length = n

for (var i = 0; i<= n; i++) {

this[i] = 0

}

return this

}

// Define a custom object named prodobj (Product Object).

// An array of these objects will act as our product/price list.

function prodobj(name, unitprice) {

this.name = name

this.unitprice = unitprice

}

// Define a new custom object named ordobj (Order Object).

// Will house real numbers from order form to help with math.

function ordobj(prodsub, qty, unitprice, extprice) {

this.prodsub = prodsub

this.qty = qty

this.unitprice = unitprice

this.extprice = extprice

}

</SCRIPT>

</HEAD>
<BODY aLink=#8a8a8a bgColor=#ffffff
link=#ff0000 text=#000000 vLink=#215e21>
<H3 align=center><FONT color=#0000ff><FONT size=+1>'shop_name ΦΟΡΜΑ ΠΑΡΑΓΓΕΛΙΑΣ</FONT></FONT></H3>
<P>Επιλέξτε προϊόντα για παραγγελία <BR>
<SCRIPT >

//Create a new array named prodlist with six elements.

prodlist = new BuildZeroArray(ProductsInList) //Refers to global variable ProductsInList

//Populate that array with this product info.

//The first item, prodlist[0] must be a "non-product" with

//a unitprice of zero.

prodlist[0] = new prodobj('-none-',0)

prodlist[1] = new prodobj('ΝΤΟΝΑΤΣ ΜΕ ΣΟΚΟΛΑΤΑ',0)

prodlist[2] = new prodobj('Bombastic Gadget',0)

prodlist[3] = new prodobj('Cosmic Wingydingy',0)

prodlist[4] = new prodobj('Desultory Doodad',0)


//Create a new array, named ordData, that contains empty Order Objects.

ordData = new MakeArray(RowsInForm)

for (var i=1; i<= RowsInForm; i++) {

ordData[i] = new ordobj(0,0,0,0)}

</SCRIPT>

<FORM name=ordform action="mailto:mymail@gmail.com" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"></P>
<CENTER>
<P><! Display the table header></P></CENTER>
<TABLE align=center border=1>
<CENTER>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TH width=192>
<CENTER><B>Προϊόν</B></CENTER></TH>
<TH width=72>
<CENTER><B>Ποσότητα</B></CENTER></TH>
<TH width=120>
<CENTER><B>Απόθεμα</B></CENTER></TH>


<SCRIPT type="application/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

document.charset = 'UTF-8';

for (var rownum = 1;rownum <= RowsInForm; rownum++) {

document.writeln('<TR><TD WIDTH=192>')

document.writeln('<SELECT NAME="product'+rownum+'" onChange= "updateRow('+rownum+')">')

for (i = 0; i <= ProductsInList; i++) {

document.writeln ("<OPTION>"+prodlist[i].name)

} document.writeln ('</SELECT>')

document.writeln ('</TD><TD WIDTH=72><CENTER><INPUT NAME="qty'+rownum+'" VALUE=""')
document.writeln ('</TD><TD WIDTH=72><CENTER><INPUT NAME="apothema'+rownum+'" VALUE=""')


document.write ('</TD></TR>')

}

</SCRIPT>


</P></TD>


<TABLE align=center border=1>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD width=120>
<P>Όνομα Καταστήματος:</P></TD>
<TD width=408>
<P><INPUT maxLength=75 name=onoma size=50 required></P></TD></TR>

<TR>
<TD width=120>
<P>Ημερομηνία</P></TD>
<TD width=408>
<P><INPUT maxLength=75 name=onoma size=50 required></P></TD></TR>

<TR>
<TD width=120>
<P>Υπεύθυνος Καταστήματος:</P></TD>
<TD width=408>
<P><INPUT maxLength=75 name=onoma size=50 required></P></TD></TR>


</P></CENTER>
<br><br><br>
<center><P><INPUT onclick="mailto:mymail@gmail.com" type=submit value=Send charset="UTF-8">
<INPUT type=reset value=Reset> </center>
</FORM></P>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By "non utf characters" do you mean you've got UTF-16 chars mixed in with UTF-8 chars?

Comment: No I use Greek language and it encoded incorrect. I tryed windows-1253 also but still no change.

Answer (score 0):

The display problems might have to do with you not passing valid HTML to the `document.writeln` method. You are writing opening tags, but not closing tag, which creates an unbalanced document tree. Basically, you are literally writing HTML syntax errors using JavaScript. You are better off concatenating a string of html and writing all the HTML at once in a single call to `document.write`.

At the beginning of the JavaScript that writes out the table cells, add this:

```
var html = [];
```

Now replace every occurrence of `document.write` and `document.writeln` with `html.push(...)`.

In the very last line of JavaScript, just do:

```
document.write(html.join(""));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tryed this but absolutely nothing changed.Any othe suggestions?